# Find a real number in a set of complex numbers

Tags: vba, excel, complex-numbers, cubic

I am looking for a way to find a real number in a set of complex numbers in excel-vba. More specifically I have a set of three results out of which one is known to be real and two are known to be complex, however, I don't know which of the results is the real one. The problem is made more complicated by the fact that due to rounding errors in intermediate calculation steps it often happens that the imaginary component of the real number doesn't cancel out to exactly 0 (as it should).

The method I'm currently considering to use consists of the following steps:

1. Determine the value of the Real component of each of the three
   results.
2. Determine the absolute value of the Imaginary component of each of
   the three results.
3. Determine the minimum value of these three results.
4. Compare each of the Absolute Imaginary components to the minimum value. When
   these match, take the corresponding real component as the final
   result.

The code would look like this:

```
Z1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.ImReal ( Application.WorksheetFunction.ImSum (xi1, x1i2, x1i3) )
Z2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.ImReal ( Application.WorksheetFunction.ImSum (xi1, x2i2, x2i3) )
Z3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.ImReal ( Application.WorksheetFunction.ImSum (xi1, x3i2, x3i3) )
ZIm1 = Abs ( Application.WorksheetFunction.Imaginary ( Application.WorksheetFunction.ImSum (xi1, x1i2, x1i3) ) )
ZIm2 = Abs ( Application.WorksheetFunction.Imaginary ( Application.WorksheetFunction.ImSum (xi1, x2i2, x2i3) ) )
ZIm3 = Abs ( Application.WorksheetFunction.Imaginary ( Application.WorksheetFunction.ImSum (xi1, x3i2, x3i3) ) )
ZImMin = Min (ZIm1, ZIm2, ZIm3)
If Zim1 = ZImMin Then
    ZImID = Z1
    ElseIf Zim2 = ZImMin Then
    ZImID = Z2
    Else ZImID = Z3
EndIf
```

I think this should work, however, I haven't tried to run it yet. Can anyone suggest a better way to find the Real solution?

This issue is part of finding the solution(s) to a cubic equation according to [this method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pSkX.jpg):

Thanks!

Comment: what are `ImReal`, `ImSum` and  `Imaginary`?

Comment: These are worksheetfunctions specifically for use with complex numbers. ImReal returns the Real component of a complex number, Imaginary returns the Imaginary component of a complex number and ImSum adds up complex numbers.

Comment: well, then I suppose you have to call them like `Application.WorksheetFunction.ImReal(...)` and the likes

Comment: Oops. I didn't realise this because I copied the formulas from a worksheet and just replaced the cell references with the appropriate variables. I modified the code accordingly now.

Comment: now go on with your tests and come back if you have any issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider not only the imaginary part to be closest to zero but the relation between real and imaginary part. Example:
z1=2,35+0,25i
z2=14+1,3i

where in fact z2 is closer to a real number. The measure for this is the angle between the real and complex part. IMARGUMENT(z) returns this angle.
Example:

```
Public Function realIndex(rng As Range) As Long
' returns the row index into a column of complex values closest to a real number

    Dim values() As Variant
    Dim angle As Double, minangle As Double, i As Long, idx As Long

    values = rng  ' complex numbers in values(i,1)

    minangle = 100#
    For i = LBound(values, 1) To UBound(values, 1)
        angle = Application.WorksheetFunction.ImArgument(values(i, 1))
        If angle < minangle Then
            minangle = angle
            idx = i
        End If
    Next i
    realIndex = idx
End Function
```

**edit** in response to comments:
Taking abs(sin(angle)) reduces the ambiguity of a negative angle around -pi. But, as ImArgument essentially is arctan(Im(x)/Re(x)) and there is an equivalence for sin(arctan(x)), we can use this:

```
Public Function MostReal(rng As Range) As Double
' returns from a column of complex values the one closest to a real number

    Dim values() As Variant
    Dim val As Double, minval As Double, absSize As Double, imSize As Double
    Dim i As Long, idx As Long

    values = rng  ' complex numbers in rows = values(i, 1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(values, 1)
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            absSize = Abs(.Imaginary(values(i, 1)))
            imSize = .ImAbs(values(i, 1))
            val = IIf(imSize > 0#, absSize / imSize, 0#)
        End With
        If i = 1 Or val < minval Then
            minval = val
            idx = i
            If minval = 0# Then Exit For ' it doesn't get any better than this
        End If
    Next i
    realIndex = values(idx, 1)
End Function
```

The criterion is the ratio of the imaginary part to the absolute value of the complex number - the closer to zero, the closer to a real number. The second code returns that value (instead of the index into the column of values), and it chooses the initial minimum value in a more safe way.

Comment: It’s a very elegant approach to use the angle as criterion. I’ll use that. However, an angle of n * pi also corresponds to a real number. So I will evaluate the value of Abs(Sin(angle)) to be minimized. 

Your approach to loop through the array and each time check if the angle is smaller than the minimum so far is much more elegant than my approach. I’ll use that as well, though I’ll use the first value as initial guess and then only check the remaining values.

Comment: Starting with "minangle = 100" only makes sure any other real angle is smaller. This way you don't have to treat the first value specially.

Comment: Using a large initial value is of course fine. What is much more important is that I can't blindly trust that by identifying the minimum value of the angle I'll find the number that is closest to a real number. I have to base that judgement on Abs(Sin(Angle)). That value is always positive and is 0 when the angle is 0, pi or - pi.

Comment: Your addition to the answer is quite useful. I had to look at it carefully and draw a circle before I realised how it works. In think there is however still one very specific case where it fails. That is when one of the values is 0 + 0 * i. In that case ImAbs resturns the value 0, which will cause a #DIV/0 error for `val = Abs(.Imaginary(values(i, 1))) / .ImAbs(values(i,1))`.

Comment: Very well spotted. Error handling for this case would have to look out for `.ImAbs(x) == 0` which denotes that `x` is a real number (of zero absolute value).

Comment: I have added the check now. And corrected a gross error with the loop start value.

Comment: I’m sorry to be a spoilsport, but you forgot to add the check for 0 size for the initial minval, so here still a `#DIV/0` error could occur. In my specific case where I’m solving a cubic equation: `a*x^3+b*x^2+c*x+d=0` this can in theory occur when a & c have the same sign and d = 0. The way I wrote the rest of the function then actually results in the first value to be the real (0) value.

Besides this very minor flaw your solution covers all bases.

Comment: Code corrected, it solves the starting value in an easy way.

Comment: I think the code now really does cover all the bases without any risk of errors. With a minor change by substituting `absSize = Abs(.Imaginary(values(i, 1)))` with `absSize = Abs(.ImReal(values(i, 1)))` it could also be used the find a purely imaginary number in a set of complex numbers (though I have no idea in what kind of situation this might be useful).